# Place the data from database to bootstrap

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get data from the database and write them to the following bootstrap structure: 1 row - 3 columns, 1 row - 3 columns, 1 row - 3 columns.

The following bootstrap structure

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-2">
       some content     
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-2">
       some content         
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-2">
       some content     
   </div>

</div>
```

I just can not figure out how to construct a cycle. Stuck on this place.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $counter ++;

        if($counter == 1 || $counter % 3 === 0) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
        } 

        echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';

        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<p>' . $row["name"] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<p>' . $row["email"] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<p>' . $row["comment"] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';

        if($counter % 3 === 0) {
            echo '</div>';
        } 

}
```

Comment: What output are you currently getting that you do not expect?

Comment: There is some problem with rows. First, one row is created, where everything else is written.

Comment: I am not sure that helps me identify any issues at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task led to the discovery that before composing algorithms in the code, I need to draw a scheme on a piece of paper. Than test the output on a piece of paper. As a result, I found such a simple solution.

```
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $counter ++;

    if($counter == 1) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    } 

    echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["name"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["email"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["comment"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';

    if($counter == 3) {
        echo '</div>';
        $counter = 0;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//$counter should be set out here to 1...
//Start here with row don't have to worry about 1
echo '<div class="row">';    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){                    

    //Other echo stuff...

    //Check if 3 yet
    if($counter == 3) {
        //reset to 0 cause you will incrment
        $counter = 0; 
        //end and start new div
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
    } 
    $counter ++;
}
//Close it up unless it is always ending on 3?
//Probably want some more checking here somehow
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if($counter % 3 === 0) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    } 

    echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["name"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["email"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' . $row["comment"] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '</div>';

    if($counter % 3 === 2) {
        echo '</div>';
    } 
    $counter++;
}
//if last row has less then 3 items then close the outer row
if($counter % 3 !== 0) {
    echo '</div>';
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtba1xmf/) with simulated output for 7 items